# How do I add links into comments?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

I was trying to direct a person to the tour when I realized that I did not know how to put links in comments. How do I do it?

Comment: I don't know, and I wish I knew.  Also in chat messages.  I usually just put a bare url surrounded by whitespace, which gets linked, but then I don't get to specify the link text.  I don't use the bracket-parenthesis syntax by principle, because it doesn't work for urls that contain a closing parenthesis.

Comment: @b_jonas it does, you just have to put a second one after the link. [(Example)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_51_(film))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[link text](http://example.com)` is how you do it. It works in posts too.

If you go to post a comment, there is a link to a 'help'  page. [That page](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)<sup>1</sup>  says:

> Comments support only bold, italic, code and links; in addition, a few shorthand links are available.
>
> `_italic_` and `**bold**` text,
>   inline `code in backticks`,
>   and `[basic links](http://example.com)`.
>   Supported shorthand links:
>
> `[meta]` – link to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name (e.g. "Super User Meta"). Does nothing if the site doesn't have (or already is) a Meta site.
>
> `[main]` – like `[meta]`, just the other way around.
>
> `[edit]` – link to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is respected).
>
> `[tag:tagname]` and `[meta-tag:tagname]` – link to the given tag's page. Link text is the name of the tag.meta-tag only works on meta sites.
>
> `[help]`, `[help/on-topic]`, `[help/dont-ask]`, `[help/behavior]` and [meta-help] – link to frequently visited pages of the help center. Link text is "help center" (capitalization is respected). All links point to the main site.
>
> `[tour]` – link to the Tour page. Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected).
>
> `[so]`, `[pt.so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – link to the given site. Link text is the site name.
>
> `[chat]` – link to the current site's chat site, the link text being "{site name} Chat".
>
> `[ask]`, `[answer]` – link to the How to Ask or How to Answer page.
>
> `[something.se]` – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name. Use `[ubuntu.se]` for Ask Ubuntu.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>I used `[that page](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)` here...</sub>

Comment: Cool! I've been doing links the hard way. :-]

Answer (score 7):

From [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/278659):

- `[meta]` – link to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name, "Literature Meta". Does nothing in comments on Meta itself.
- `[main]` – like [meta], just the other way around.
- `[edit]` – link to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalisation is respected).
- `[help]` should be obvious. `[meta-help]` links to "What is meta?" (/help/whats-meta), `[help/on-topic]` links to "What topics can I ask about here?" (/help/on-topic), `[help/dont-ask]` links to "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" (/help/dont-ask), `[help/behavior]` links to "What kind of behavior is expected of users?" (/help/behavior). Link text for all of these is "help center" .
- `[tour]` and `[meta-tour]` – equivalent to the FAQ version, but links to the site's Tour page (resp. the meta site's Tour page). Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected). Legacy names `[about]` and `[meta-about]` are still supported.
- `[ask]`, `[answer]` – link to the "How to Ask" / "How to Answer" page.
- `[so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`/`[meta.se]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – link to the given site ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), the [Stack Exchange portal](http://stackexchange.com/)). Link text is the site name.
- `[something.se]` – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name. Use `[ubuntu.se]` for Ask Ubuntu. `[meta.something.se]` links to the meta site.
- `[chat]` – link to the current site's chat site, http://chat.stackexchange.com/, showing a list of active rooms from the referring site), the link text being "Literature Chat".

Except for `[chat]` and `[edit]`, and with the addition of `[chat-faq]`, these also work in chat.

---

See also [this page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) from the help centre.